# Make navigation div expand entire height

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a navigation div on the left of my page. I want it to span the entire height of the page. This is fine (and easy) if the content doesn't require the page to scroll, however, there are a few pages where I have lots of content, so the page must scroll. However, the div ends just a little bit below where the page did.

Here's the basics of the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> (Title) </title>
        <div id="header>
            <h1> Header </h1>
        </div>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            (nav)
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            (Content)
        </div>
    </body
</html>
```

And the (I think) relevant CSS is:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100;
}
html{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The content div expands all the way to the bottom of the screen, but not the nav div. Any idea what needs to change to make it look right?

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: full base.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %} Title Goes Here {% endblock %}</title>
    <div id="header">
      <h1> {% block head %} Header Goes Here {% endblock %}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}logo.png" alt="logo" width="125" height="125">
      <!--<img src="http://www.tecnospotsolar.com/content/images/yingli_logo_1.png" alt="logo" width="270" height="81"> -->
    </div>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}layout1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="nav">
      {% block nav %}
      <ul>
    <li><a href="/workflow/"> Home </a> 
    <li><a href="/workflow/new"> New Entry </a>  
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/request/"> Requests </a> 
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/approved/"> Approved </a> 
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/rejected/"> Rejected </a> 
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/fulfilment/"> Fulfilment </a> 
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/poa/"> POA </a>
    <li><a href="/workflow/list/confirmed/">  Confirmed </a>
    <li><a href="/workflow/profile/"> Profile </a>
    </div>
      </ul>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      {% block content %} Body Goes Here {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="clear"/>

     <div id="login">
      <a href="/workflow/login/"> Login</a>/<a href="/workflow/logout/">Logout</a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS...

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100;
}

head {
  min-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
}

html{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body{ 
  height: 100%
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push{
  height: 4em;
}

/********* ID's ************/



#nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid #00047A;
  border-left: 5px solid #EBDE95;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #EDF3FE;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#nav a:visited{
  color: #040638;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:link{
  color: #040638;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#nav  ul li{
  height: 2em;
}

#nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
}

#nav li:hover a{
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #13118C;
  width: 100%;
}




#content {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 95px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#content ul{
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #EDF3FE;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #00047A;
  border-left: 5px solid #EBDE95;
  border-top: 5px solid #EBDE95;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#logo{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -17px;

  padding-left: 100px;
}

#login{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#warning{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}

/********** CLASSES *************/

.field_error{
  background-color: #F9FFAD;
}

.button-container form,
.button-container form div {
  display: inline;
}

.button-container button{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.clear{
  clear:both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: You should move your header elements into the body section. Not the head.

Comment: You have an extra div right before the `ul` closes. Also, why don't you close the `<li>` tags?

Comment: Yeah, the div was from another suggestion that I tried, guess I didn't delete it all.

Answer (score 1):

To make a child element's height 100% you need to set the height of all the parent elements so add this in your css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

If your background has stopped scrolling then it is because of your `overflow: hidden;` try removing that, and it would work. :)

Hope it helped!

Comment: That didn't fix it. If the page is the size of the screen it works fine, but if it needs to be larger (i.e. scroll) the background stops where the screen does.

Comment: That's because of your `overflow:hidden;` try removing that.

Comment: Nope. Still ends short of where it should.

Comment: please post a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a clearing div after your content div.

In your HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> (Title) </title>
        <div id="header>
            <h1> Header </h1>
        </div>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="nav">
                (nav)
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                (Content)
            </div>
            <div class="clear"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.clear
{
   clear:both; 
   margin:0; 
   padding:0; 
   height:0;
}

#nav
{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How about `overflow:visible` instead of hidden?

Comment: That succeeded in completely breaking the layout. :( Still no fix.

Comment: Maybe you could show us some more of the source code? Or even your website?

Comment: I'm using the Django runserver, so I unfortunately can't send you a link to the page. I'll add the full code for the base template above.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that I don't particularly love, but we'll see if we can live with it. I have changed the header and navigation divs to `position: fixed` so they always appear at the same place on the screen. I then had to give the content the attribute `z-index: -1;` so that it goes 'behind' the header and navigation when scrolling. Honestly, there are only a few scenarios where this will even be encountered, so I think it will work for us.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code that you provided and added the rest that was needed to make it work. If this doesn't help then I think something else is causing the problem and not the code that you posted. If so,  could you post a link to the source or a jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/G2nAw/1/

HTML CODE

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        (nav)
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        (Content)
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
 body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100;
    }
    html{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    }

    #nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    left:0;
    top:0; 
    background-color:red;
    }

#content{
    background-color:blue;
    width:500px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-left:130px;
}
```

Comment: Hm. This is interesting. If I remove the `position: absolute` from the #content css, I can make the navigation height correct, however, then the height and width of the content block gets totally screwed up, and the background doesn't extend the full area it should. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

you need to encase your navigation div into a parent div

make the parent div 100% height with the tiling bg image

then insert the navigation div inside of its parent relative to top so it stays
at the top of its parent div

hope that helps